# Trying to use dojo 1.6 auto loader 

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm trying to work out how to load a module using example http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/registerModulePath.html

I have the following structure (highlighting what I believe to be the important files):

```
/index.html (code below)
/dojo-1.6.1/dojo/dojo.js
/dojo-1.6.1/j_test/test1234.js <- for method 1 loading
/xj_test/test1234.js <- for method 2 loading
```

I have the following code on the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/dojo-1.6.1/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    dojo.ready(function(){
        //alert("Dojo version " + dojo.version");

        //method 1
        dojo.require("j_test.test1234");

        //method2
        dojo.registerModulePath("xj_test", "../../xj_test");
        dojo.require("xj_test.test1234");
    });
</script>
```

For method 1 I get the error message:

> could not load 'j_test.test1234'; last tried '../j_test/test1234.js'

For method 2, I get the error:

> Could not load 'xj_test.test1234'; last tried '../../xj_test/test1234.js'

I was expecting dojo to work out the correct path auto-magically but I guess I must be missing something? I am using dojo1.6.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Did you remember to put the `dojo.provide` call in `test1234.js`?
2. Dojo 1.7 has a brand new and awesomer module system. Are you sure you don't want that instead? :)

Comment: 1) thanks! dojo.provide did the job! Anyone reading this should read http://www.enterprisedojo.com/2010/08/24/writing-modular-javascript-with-dojo



2) The internal framework is using 1.6 but we're moving to 1.7 at some point